# React native android stuck in :app:mergeDebugResources

Tags: android, react-native

When i run `react-native run-android` android building stuck in `:app:mergeDebugResources` and does not report any error.

Here is my package.json file :

```
{
"name": "listeo",
"version": "0.0.1",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
},
"dependencies": {
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "0.48.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "21.0.2",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "3.0.2",
    "jest": "21.0.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.12"
},
"jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
}
}
```

Android build tools version is : 23.0.1

I tested it with android build tools 25 and 26 but didn't fixed.

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 5):

try to remove the node_modules folder, then run `npm install`, also dont forget to check and update the required components on your SDK Manager, after that you can `react-native run-android`

Comment: I did it multiple times but not fixed

Answer (score 0):

try with run `cd android && ./gradlew clean && cd.. && react-native run-android`
also keep build tool as it's default also be patient some times takes time

Comment: how long it is taking?

Comment: until now it is 1 hour

Comment: what operating system you have?

Comment: Operating system is windows

Comment: did you clicked on terminal window it is pausing activity try click control + c

Comment: Yes i did it... thank you helping but this not helping